# Selenium Webdriver - Can't Get Nested Element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I have various divs on a page that have the class name - list-group. I'm trying to get the 6th one, then get the list of all the divs in this div with the class name list-group-item.

I keep getting an error saying - "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to By".

I have the following code in Java. Can someone point out what the error is? I thought getting the element by the index and then finding the element within that would do the trick (worked for me in C#).

```
public List<WebElement> Authorities(){

    List<WebElement> Authorities = Driver.findElements(By.className("list-group")[5].findElements(By.className("list-group-item")));

    return Authorities;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML or provide a link to the page because the answer provided is not good practice. You shouldn't have an XPath that starts at the HTML tag and it shouldn't be that many nested levels.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick-

```
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[6]")).findElements(By.className("list-group-itme"));
```

Comment: You must be kidding! Give the link to the page, I'll crate you a normal selector.